# THE program throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, How to Overcome?

Tags: java

THE program works fine but throws Array Index Out Of Bound Exception, please help How to Overcome this problem? THE program works fine but throws Array Index Out Of Bound Exception, please help How to Overcome this problem?

```
package coreJava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
    public static int count = 0;
    public static int position = 0;
    public static boolean flag = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
       // int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23 };

         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter number of elements you want in array:");
         int n = s.nextInt();
         int a[] = new int[n];
         System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");

         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             a[i] = s.nextInt();
         }

         findMissingNumbers(a, position);
    }

    private static void findMissingNumbers(int a[], int position) {
        if (position == a.length - 1)
            return;

        for (; position < a[a.length - 1]; position++) {
            if ((a[position] - count) != position) {
                System.out.println("Missing Number: " + (position + count));
                flag = true;
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag) {
            flag = false;
            findMissingNumbers(a, position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when does it throw that error?, i dont see it throwing that error..

Comment: can you please tell us what line is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
for (; position < a[a.length - 1]; position++)
```

to:

```
for (; position < a.length; position++)
```

Answer (score 0):

in line,  if ((a[position] - count) != position) {

you may get the exception. That's because position can be higher than a.length-1 Please check the algorithm. since the first number you get as input may lesser than other input values.